# How to specify database for SQL Server catalog in Presto?

Tags: sql-server, presto, trino

I specified following catalog for SQL Server

```
connector.name=sqlserver
connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.1
connection-user=build_agent
connection-password=build_agent
```

When I try running queries against it, it seems that I can access `master` database only. How can I specify specific database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Trino (formerly Presto SQL) SQL Server connector documentation (https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/sqlserver.html):

```
connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;database=<database>
```

Comment: I was reading https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/sqlserver.html docs and there is nothing about that. Prestodb ... Prestosql ... :)

Comment: "Prestodb ... Prestosql ..." -- i understand the confusion. You can get more information on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) and also in https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/380